# Can Thread method be used in my class without extending Thread Class

Tags: java

I am new to threads and while learning it i cant understand the following,

```
public class myClass 
{ 
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException
    {
        String[] myString = {"Object","Classes","Static","Final"};
        for(int i=0;i<myString.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(myString[i]);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
    }
}
```

How come I'm able to use thread method without extending Thread class?

Comment: Method `Thread.sleep()` is `static`. That's why you are able to use it without even instantiating it.

Comment: Thanks for the short and apt reply...

Answer (score 5):

sleep is a static method. It doesn't require an instance to be called.

Comment: Yes, this is just the same as the way you're using `System` in `System.out.println()`

Answer (score 1):

There are only 2 ways to make a class/method 'threadable' in Java. Extending [Thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) or implementing [Runnable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html). What you are doing there is Thread.sleep() which is simply saying sleep the **current** thread.

It is just a static method supplied by Thread and as you have discovered doesn't really have much to do with multithreading specifically. A static method means an object of the containing class does not need to be instantiated to invoke the method which is why you can call sleep() without extending Thread.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [static methods in the Java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html). Learn the basics of the language before playing with threads. Threads are a difficult thing to master, and if you don't know what a static method is, it's too early to start using them, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using astatic member method of `Thread` class, that's why you are able to use the `sleep()` function without requiring an instance.

Answer (score 0):

sleep() is a static method of the 'Thread' class. as you might know static methods are invoked directly by the sysntax

```
MyClass.myStaticMethod().
```

you don't need to instantiate a Thread object to call sleep() method.